# How to set breakpoints & command line arguments in VS code debugging mode?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

**Backgroud:**

- I am using VS code. I am trying to run a python project.
- I am on Ubuntu 18, Python 3.6 anaconda installation.

**Issue:**

I set a breakpoint in another file which has a function that is being called in my main file and in the debugging mode, VS code doesn't stop at all on the breakpoint.

How can I set a breakpoint in another file that is not the main.py?

**Additional:**

I had another question, how can I get command line arguments when running a program in debugging mode? Is hardcoding the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking in the gutter to set a breakpoint in another file should work. Make sure the code is actually being executed and that you are running the latest version of the extension.

As for setting arguments, see the [debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and specifically the section on [`args` for your `launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough information to help. Are you setting breakpoints in files that are not in your workspace but instead in your `site-packages`? If so then that's on purpose as you can't traverse into library code (yet; we are planning to add a setting to let you).